# Laptop won't boot to GUI when using Linux bootable HD

Tags: linux, boot, bios, bootable-media

I am currently trying to get my laptop to boot via bootable HD.  The HD has Linux Mandrake installed.  The BIOS process works just fine, but the end result is a terminal rather than the Linux GUI.  I repeated the process on a single-board and chassis combo and it worked just fine.  No hiccups at all.  Anyone know why this happens/how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, does the terminal header read "Busybox"?

You probably did not "cleanly umnount" your system partition when you last shut it down, or something went wrong editing your main partition. I have had this happen several times when holding down the power button rather then selecting "Shut Down" from the menu. The solution:

1. Type `exit`. It might disappear, and your system will boot normally. It might also report

   ```
   /dev/sdaX contains a filesystem with errors, check forced.
   ```

   where the X is you partition number (mine is 4).
2. If you got the errors message, run the following command

   ```
   fsck /dev/sdaX -y
   ```

   Replace the X with your partition number.
3. Type `exit` again. You system should go straight to the GUI.

If the partition was modified, you should get random things marked as "fixed" (like nonexistent UTF-8 characters, bad bitmaps, etc.). If it was not cleanly unmounted, it may say that inode XXXXXX reported a faulty location, and was fixed (XXXXXX is the inode number).

Whwn running `fsck`, if it says something and `(y):`, press Y. If the exact same message appears again, press Enter.

Comment: exit simply logged me out and asked for the log in again.  Thank you for the advice though.